# How do I set permissions on dynamically linked files?

Tags: file-permissions, installshield, installshield-2010

I have an InstallScript installer that utilizes dynamic file links for several components. These components contain configuration files that standard users should be able to edit. We recently discovered that when these files are installed on Windows Server 08, the permissions are set to full access for the Administrators group, but only read & execute access for the Users group.  The typical install location is C:\programName.

I've tried creating new files manually as an admin (right click - new text file) in the C:\programName directory, and they are generated with identical permissions. I'm assuming that this is just the standard permission setup for new files.

Is there any way, within InstallShield, to set the permissions for dynamically linked files or the directory containing them?

I've looked for permission settings in

- Organization -> Components
- Application Data -> Files and Folders

but I haven't found anything. The documentation on dynamic file links makes no mention of permissions.

We are using InstallShield 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally these permissions are a good thing; they're inherited from their parent folders. Non-administrator users (including the limited access admin before accepting a UAC prompt) should be unable to modify files under `Program Files` or `C:` so I would suggest addressing this concern in your application (for instance by using each user's Documents folder). Since you don't talk about why you need it, it's hard to say with certainty if this applies to your case.

If it turns out it does make sense to address this in the installation instead of the application, you can use the [SetObjectPermissions](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield16langref/setobjectpermissions.htm) API to set permissions programmatically.

Comment: This looks like a viable solution, thanks. (I do realize that circumventing the standard security policies is less than ideal, but I'm not the one who gets to make that decision.)

Answer (score 0):

In "Files and Folders" page right-click the file or folder, select **Properties** and click the **Permissions** button. In the "Permissions" dialog you can then right-click in the *Name(s)* list and use the **New** context menu option to add a new permission.

If the option is not available for a file, you can try setting it on the parent folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a Permissions option in the destination computer's folder properties. I can't check the individual files, as they don't show up in the Files and Folders view (they are generated by the project build, just before the installer is built.)